# How to know if H1B receipt is for concurrent H1B or normal H1B

Tags: usa, h1b-visas, concurrent-h1b

My friend applied for concurrent H1B for part time job on weekend. He has to take decision that he can join or not :).

His employer gave him H1B receipt I-797C, but from the receipt he don't know if its for concurrent H1B or not.

He has to take decision to join or not, because if its not concurrent H1B, then it will create problems in his normal H1B process as he might be working 16-20 hours per week for that employer.

Let me know if is there any way to know from the receipt number that if its concurrent h1 or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as a "receipt for concurrent H1b". The concurrent H1b application is just an H1b application, but the terms of employment should explicitly call out that this is a part-time position in addition and not instead of the other H1b full time position (it should be explicitly checked on the I-129, Part 2 Question 2, checkbox d).

I don't believe there's anything mentioned to that on the I-797C for the petition. You can ask for the copies of the petition and the LCA submitted to check how the position is defined.